# Descobrir se um site está ou não no ar

Tags: php, ip

Existe alguma função em PHP para descobrir se um endereço IP(entende-se por site) esta no ar ou não?

Encontrei essa [função](http://wbruno.com.br/php/verificar-com-php-se-o-site-esta-online-no-ar/) na WEB mas ela não me satisfez.... ela demora muito pra carregar.

```
function curl_info($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );

    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $info = curl_getinfo( $ch );

    return $info;
}

$site = 'http://www.locaweb.com.br';
$info = curl_info( $site );
if( $info['http_code']==200 ) {
    echo '<u>'.$site . '</u> - <strong>está no ar!!</strong><br />';
} else {
    echo '<u>'.$site . '</u> - está fora do ar<br />';
}
```

Comment: Como assim se um IP está online? Você quer verificar oque exatamente? Um serviço ou usuário?

Comment: Pelo que eu percebi quer verificar se um site está "online" certo? Se for esse o caso acho que essa é mesmo a melhor solução. Demora muito? Quanto tempo em segundos? Ah mais uma coisa o site pode estar online mas na página estar "em manutenção", não sei se é relevante, mas fica a ressalva.

Comment: pior que demora rs, por exemplo, testando 'https://www.google.com.br' essa função leva 21 segundos para terminar... não sei se eu estou fazendo alguma coisa errada, ou se isso está certo

Comment: A solução poderia ser em Javascript?

Comment: poderia ser sim, mas acho difícil criar uma solução desse tipo

Comment: Pergunta rápida: não seria mais fácil usar um serviço como o Pingdom? (a não ser que você queira, de fato, desenvolver um script para seu propósito)

Comment: não não, o proposito é outro....

Answer (score 6):

1) Usando *fsockopen*, atente-se para o formato da URL

```
if( fsockopen( 'www.locaweb.com.br' , 80 , $errno , $errstr , 30 ) ){
    echo 'site online!';
} else {
    echo 'site offline.';
}
```

---

2) Usando *checkdnsrr*: *Verifica os registros de DNS que correspondem a um determinado nome de host ou o endereço IP Internet*.

```
checkdnsrr( 'google.com' ) // TRUE
checkdnsrr( 'yaruuu.com' ) // FALSE
```

---

3) Usando *curl*

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.locaweb.com.br');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$data = curl_exec($ch);  
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
curl_close($ch);  

if( $httpcode >= 200 && $httpcode < 300 ){  
    echo 'site online!';
} else {
    echo 'site offline.';
}
```

No caso de `CURL`, a URL *http://www.locaweb.com.br* retorna um status **301** de redirecionamento para a URL *http://www.locaweb.com.br/default.html*, podemos aceitar o site como ONLINE. No exemplo acima ele não considera status de redirecionamento como *ONLINE*, mas você pode alterar e aceitar estes casos:

status redirect:

```
300 => 'Multiple Choices',
301 => 'Moved Permanently',
302 => 'Found', // 1.1
303 => 'See Other',
304 => 'Not Modified',
305 => 'Use Proxy',
// 306 is deprecated but reserved
307 => 'Temporary Redirect',
```

Cabe a você definir o status que vai ser válido como *ONLINE*.

Answer (score 1):

Tinha o mesmo problema e alterei o script.
A "responsabilidade" de obter dados da página passou para outra função.

Função para verificar apenas se o link informado retorna alguma resposta:

```
//verifica se o link informado retorna alguma resposta
function isUrl($_sUrl){
    $bRet = false;

    $cl = curl_init($_sUrl);
    curl_setopt($cl,CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($cl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);
    curl_setopt($cl,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
    curl_setopt($cl,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
    curl_setopt($cl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($cl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($cl);
    curl_close($cl);
    if($response) $bRet = true;

    return $bRet;
}
```

No meu caso, verifico se existe algum vídeo na página:

```
function getVideo($_sUrl){
    $sVideo = '';
    //necessário a extensão php_openssl activa para ulr's com https
    $html = new DOMDocument();
    @$html->loadHTML(file_get_contents($_sUrl));
    $aMeta = $html->getElementsByTagName('meta');
    foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta) {
        if($meta->getAttribute('property')=='og:video'){
            $sVideo = $meta->getAttribute('content');
            break;
        }
    }

    return $sVideo;
 }
```

Para utilizar o código acima:

```
$sUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZ5gVkSjC8k';
if(isUrl($sUrl))
    $sVideo = getVideo($sUrl);
```

Comment: funcionou não mano...
Usei assim:
$sUrl = 'https://www.google.com.br/';
isUrl($sUrl);

E não me da nenhum retorno =x

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio você tem que adaptar a sua necessidade, veja o exemplo que postei, verifica primeiro se existe alguma resposta do servidor (função isUrl) e depois procura pela meta tag 'og:video' (função getVideo), que no caso do google.com.br não existe, logo o retorno da função getVideo é vazio.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio a função isUrl retorna true/false, logo você deve fazer um "if", por exemplo, echo isUrl('sua_url') ? "online" : "offline";

Answer (score 1):

Não sou expert na parte de Web, mas acredito que se você executar um Get no endereço e retornar com sucesso, o endereço está "on line"

```
var urlValida = '/echo/html/';
var urlInvalida =  '/NaoExiste/html/';

$.ajax({    
    type: 'GET',
    url: urlValida,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(urlValida + ' OnLine');
    }
}).error( function () {
        alert(urlValida + 'OffLine');
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: urlInvalida,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(urlInvalida + ' OnLine');
    }
}).error( function () {
        alert(urlInvalida + 'OffLine');
});
```

O código pode ser testado neste exemplo no [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pL7w8x0e/)

Comment: Acho que voce não entendeu velho kk
Não quero procurar arquivos dentro do meu projeto e etc.... quero verificar sites externos, sites de outros servidores, tipo o comando ping do cmd

Comment: for example... ping www.google.com.br me retorna que os pacotes foram enviados e retornaram com sucesso, ou seja, o site está 'enxergavel', online

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Mas foi isso que eu fiz, estou desconsiderando os dados retornados. Apenas estou validando se houve ou não sucesso na chamada remota. Eu pensei em usar HEAD ou invés de GET mas não sei se todo servidor HTTP responde a HEAD. Veja o exemplo do JSFiddle, só não pude usar URLs reais pois existe bloqueio, mas se vc rodar o código na sua página, com as urls postadas o resultado será provavelmente o mesmo

Comment: Bom, nesse seu exemplo, var urlValida = 'www.google.com.br';
Daria online correto?

Comment: Sim, mas fora do JSFiddle por ele não permitir chamadas externas. e `http://www.googlelalalalala.com.br` daria offline